# Run django application on Background with PM2

Tags: python, django, pm2

Hello i have a django application which runs smoothly with **`python3 manage.py runserver`**. But to run it all time i need to use any process manager or manually create a service. I want to run it with pm2.

But problem occurs when i try to run the app with **`pm2`** as a process. Below is my pm2 config file.

```json
{
   apps:
      [{
        name: "lab",
        script: "/home/ubuntu/sample-django-app/manage.py",
        args: ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"],
        exec_mode: "fork",
        instances: "1",
        wait_ready: true,
        autorestart: true,
        max_restarts: 5,
        interpreter : "/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3"
      }]
}
```

But the following error occurs

```
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/sample-django-app/manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/sample-django-app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "/home/ubuntu/sample-django-app/manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

here I have installed Django and the app runs smoothly with 
**`python3 manage.py runserver`** Any help with this? Is my config file okay or not?

Comment: can u see Django in `/home/ubuntuvenv/bin/python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: I think yes 
Django==3.2.7
django-seed==0.2.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4

Comment: @rabbit.aaron can you please see the issue? or help me out here??

Comment: @rabbit.aaron hey you there? just figured it out

Comment: @rabbit.aaron thanks for the help but we were missing cwd instead of cmd